# После login/registration, перезагружаю страницу -> POST запрос -> CSRF token missing or incorrect

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

У меня есть два метода для регистрации и авторизации в context_proccessors.py.
Эти методы доступны на любой странице сайта, чтобы пользователь мог авторизироваться или зарегистрироваться на любой странице

```py
def login_view(request): # вьюшка авторизации

    if request.method == 'GET':
        form_log = LoginForm(request.POST or None)

        data = {
            'form_log' : form_log,
        }
        return data

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST.get('submit_type') == 'Войти':
            form_log = LoginForm(request.POST or None)
            if form_log.is_valid():
                username = form_log.cleaned_data['username']
                password = form_log.cleaned_data['password']
                user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
                if user:
                    profile = login(request, user)
                    return {}
            data = {
                'form_log' : form_log,
            }
            return data
        return {}

def registration_view(request): # вьюшка регистрации

    if request.method == 'GET':
        form_reg = RegistrationForm(request.POST or None)

        context = {
            'form_reg' : form_reg,
        }
        return context

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST.get('submit_type') == 'Зарегистрироваться':
            form_reg = RegistrationForm(request.POST or None)
            if form_reg.is_valid():
                new_user = form_reg.save(commit=False)
                new_user.username = form_reg.cleaned_data['username']
                new_user.email = form_reg.cleaned_data['email']
                new_user.save()
                new_user.set_password(form_reg.cleaned_data['password'])
                new_user.save()
                Profile.objects.create(
                    user=new_user,
                )
                user = authenticate(username=form_reg.cleaned_data['username'],                                   
                                    password=form_reg.cleaned_data['password'])
                login(request, user)
                return {}
            context = {
                'form_reg' : form_reg,
            }
            return context
        return {}
```

После авторизации или регистрации страница обновляется.
Если обновить страницу еще раз повториться POST запрос и будет ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Как сделать так чтобы после успешной авторизации или регистрации, обновив страницу POST запрос не повторялся???**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После обработки post запроса делайте редирект.

Это можно сделать через [redirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) или HttpRedirectResponse

Comment: Да но context_processors.py не может возвращать redirect, HttpRedirectResponse и остальное поэтому я реализовал ПОСТ запрос через middleware

Comment: а зачем вам middleware?